# discord.py error handling not working as it should

Tags: error-handling, discord.py

I have own code for error handling and i try that when users dont have perms to ban/kick etc someone it will send error and says what perms is missing. Now, it only says `Application did not respond`(im using @client.tree.commands). How to make it send error message? here is my code for error handling:

````
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.errors.CommandNotFound):
        return
    elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        return
    elif isinstance(error, commands.errors.MissingPermissions) or isinstance(error, discord.Forbidden):
        required_permission = error.missing_perms[0] if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions) else "Unknown Permission"
        noperms = discord.Embed(title="<a:wrong:1199385940263706765> ERROR",
                      description=f"```\nNO PERMISSIONS TO USE THIS COMMAND\n```\n**REQUIRED PERMISSIONS:**\n```\n{required_permission}\n```",
                      colour=0xf50000)
        await ctx.send(embed=noperms)
    elif isinstance(error, commands.errors.CommandOnCooldown):
        cooldown = discord.Embed(title="<a:wrong:1199385940263706765> ERROR",
                      description=f"```\nYOU NEED TO WAIT {error.retry_after:.2f} BEFORE TRYING THIS COMMAND AGAIN.\n```",
                      colour=0xf50000)
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=cooldown)
    elif isinstance(error, commands.errors.MissingRole):
        if ctx.command.name in [""]:
            await ctx.send("You need premium to use this command")
    else:
        error = discord.Embed(title="<a:wrong:1199385940263706765> ERROR",
                      description=f"**SOMETHING WEIRD HAPPENED!?**\n__**SEND THIS ERROR CODE TO BOT DEVELOPERS:**__\n\n```\n{error}\n```",
                      colour=0xf50000)
        await ctx.send(embed=error)
````

My friend tried to use it without perms and it should send error message with perms friend needs to use it

Comment: Also, forgot to say that error embed works fine (if there is error in code it will send it. the last one)

Answer (score 2):

The `on_command_error` is an event for *normal* commands, not slash commands.

To create a global error handler for app (slash) commands use the `tree.error` decorator:

```py
from discord import app_commands, Interaction

tree = client.tree

@tree.error
async def on_app_command_error(
    interaction: Interaction,
    error: app_commands.AppCommandError
):
    if isinstance(error, app_commands.MissingPermissions):
        ...  # missing perms
    elif isinstance(error, app_commands.MissingRole):
        ...  # missing role
    elif isinstance(error, app_commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        ...  # command on cooldown
```

Comment: Its not working. Still saying "application did not respond"

Comment: did you actually respond...?

Comment: Still Not working.